# Ora 01017 Invalid Username Password; with correct data

Tags: oracle-12c

I am new to oracle (enterprise:12.2.0.1) and after installation I logged in with `connect sys as sysdba`.
I also created a new user with:

```
 alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
 create user dummy identified by dummy;
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO dummy;
```

Everything went successful until now, but when I tried to log in with the new created user with 'connect dummy' I get the error: *Ora 01017 Invalid Username Password; logon denied*

After resetting the password 10 times and creating 8 new users, I am nearly 100% sure, the password and username is correct.
I read, that this problem can also appear because of the tnsnames.ora file, but I don't try to connect with TNS, so I would rule this case.

After many hours, I would now be happy, if I can get here a simple step-by-step solution and explanation.
Thank you very much and greetings from Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you were trying to connect to a different database with the user.

You should not be using

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

It is for Oracle's internal use only, you will create problems for yourself if you use it. I can only assume that you stumbled into it from a misleading answer which suggests this is the way to create users, it is not. You should be connecting to a Pluggable Database and creating a user as normal there:

```
show pdbs
```

To list the PDBs (Pluggable Databases) in your Multitenant Database.

```
alter session set container=<pdb name>;
```

To move your session to the PDB

```
create user dummy identified by dummy;
```

To create the user

```
conn dummy@<tns alias for the PDB>
```

You might need to create the tns alias first, have a look at your existing `tnsnames.ora` and create an entry which gives the PDB name as the `service_name`. Once you've created this entry, you can also use it to connect as `SYS` straight to the PDB so you can create users

```
sqlplus /@<tns alias for the PDB> as sysdba
create user dummy identified by dummy;
```

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled oracle and now it works fine.
My guess with tnsnames.ora was totally wrong and also think there was the error!

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER SYSTEM 
SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = TRUE;
```

please set this parameter to TRUE, issue will be resolved.